# How to see source code locations of docusaurus warnings?

Tags: debugging, logging, warnings, docusaurus

When I run `npm run build` to build website using docusaurus 3.0.1, I get some warnings **without any reference to problematic source files and line numbers**, like shown on the image below. How can I figure out the exact locations of problematic source files?

The same occurs when I start the development server with `npm run start`.

[image]